# Highcharts column chart no spacing wrong outer values

Tags: highcharts

With Highcharts, I wanted to create a column chart without left/right spacing. For that, I found a few posts saying to set xAxis min/max to 0.25 and number-of-items - 1.25, which seems to remove horizontal spacings.

But then, depending on the values, the columns on the edges will go up to the top and their labels won't be visible anymore.

Example:
Two charts that are only different in that the first one has xAxis min/max set to 0.25/2.75.
https://codepen.io/rolfboom/pen/qBvrQvZ

It seems this only happens for **outer values** if they are bigger (a tenth/hundredth) than the rest, like:
[20, 10, 10, 20]
[100, 100, 100, 200]

I have found that if I set an yAxis max value (to the biggest value of the dataset) manually, then the columns are displayed correctly again.

Does anyone know if this is a bug or if I am just using min/max wrong?

Codepen code from above URL:
HTML

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/11.3.0/highcharts.js"></script>
<div id="container1"></div>
<div id="container2"></div>
```

JS

```
Highcharts.chart('container1', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column',
  },
  title: {
    text: '',
  },
  yAxis: {
    tickAmount: 0,
    labels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
  },
  xAxis: {
    labels: {
      enabled: false,
    },
    tickLength: 0,
    min: 0.25,
    max: 2.75,
  },
  plotOptions: {
    "column": {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        inside: false,
      },
    }
  },
  series: [
    {
      name: '',
        data: [122, 56.2, 87, 191],
    },
  ],
});

Highcharts.chart('container2', {
    chart: {
      type: 'column',
    },
    title: {
      text: '',
    },
    yAxis: {
      tickAmount: 0,
      labels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
    },
    xAxis: {
      labels: {
        enabled: false,
      },
      tickLength: 0,
            //min: 0.25,
            //max: 2.75,
    },
    plotOptions: {
      "column": {
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          inside: false,
        },
      }
    },
    series: [
      {
        name: '',
                data: [122, 56.2, 87, 191],
      },
    ],
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer to this in the Highcharts forum: https://www.highcharts.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=190834&sid=511556b33e8e9527fcc978743061a10d#p190834

> You are correct, when setting the x-axis min & max values to e.g. 0.25/2.75, the y-axis extremes don't take into account the outer values, since they are outside of the x-axis extremes (the outer left & right column are still laid out on 0 and 3rd tick).
>
> As a workaround, you can either set the dataLabels to be rendered inside the columns, or on a load event set the y-axis max value to be slightly higher than the biggest value of the data, making enough space for the data labels to render.